# jQuery closest element that's not self

Tags: javascript, filter, coordinates, touch-event

Trying to use `document.elementFromPoint()` during a `touchEnd` event. It's working correctly, in that it's showing the highest visible element, but the problem is that I'm transforming the element that is moving so it's always the most visible.

I'm wondering if there's a combination of `elementFromPoint` and `not()` that will work? I've been testing and have only been returned `undefined`.

```
var x = orig.changedTouches[0].pageX,
    y = orig.changedTouches[0].pageY,
    d = $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).not('.moving');
```

"moving" is a class that denotes elements that are being transformed. These elements are being returned with `document.elementFromPoint()`. Logically, I'm looking for any element at those coordinates that is not moving.

Comment: you can use jquery filter(':animated')  to see if something is moving via animation

Comment: You may not like it (and it may not work), but you could use: `$(".moving").hide();`, then use `$(document.elementFromPoint(x, y))`, then `$(".moving").show();`. Since the first thing that gets evaluated is `document.elementFromPoint(x, y)`, it will always return the topmost visible element. Applying `.not(".moving")` will do nothing. Using this `hide`/`show` should not make it selectable by `elementFromPoint`

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't think this functionality can be achieved in a standard way using Javascript. However, this developer has devised a strategy that allows for tracking custom layers that should support what you need to do: http://www.vinylfox.com/forwarding-mouse-events-through-layers/